# sys.dm_database_encryption_keys not showing all encrypted databases, unless selecting the database with USE db_name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, tde

All six databases have been encrypted, but the status (in sys.dm_database_encryption_keys) is only showing correctly for three out of the six databases. To be able to see the correct status, I first need to select the database with the `USE db_name` statement.

This is the query and the output while being on `master`.

```
SELECT db.database_id, db.is_encrypted, encryption_state,
encryption_state_desc =
CASE encryption_state
WHEN '0' THEN 'No database encryption key present, no encryption'
WHEN '1' THEN 'Unencrypted'
WHEN '2' THEN 'Encryption in progress'
WHEN '3' THEN 'Encrypted'
WHEN '4' THEN 'Key change in progress'
WHEN '5' THEN 'Decryption in progress'
WHEN '6' THEN 'Protection change in progress (The certificate or asymmetric key that is encrypting the database encryption key is being changed.)'
ELSE 'No Status'
END,
percent_complete, encryptor_type 
FROM sys.databases db LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_database_encryption_keys dm ON db.database_id = dm.database_id
WHERE db.is_encrypted = 1;
```

Result:

| database_id | is_encrypted | encryption_state | encryption_state_desc | percent_complete | encryptor_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | Encrypted | 0 | ASYMMETRIC KEY |
| 5 | 1 | NULL | No Status | NULL | NULL |
| 6 | 1 | NULL | No Status | NULL | NULL |
| 7 | 1 | NULL | No Status | NULL | NULL |
| 8 | 1 | 3 | Encrypted | 0 | CERTIFICATE |
| 9 | 1 | 3 | Encrypted | 0 | CERTIFICATE |
| 10 | 1 | 3 | Encrypted | 0 | CERTIFICATE |

I presume I must have some kind of permission error or maybe a specific setting on the three databases only showing when `USING` them. I am logged on as a full administrator.

What could be the culprit?

Comment: So you have `sa` rights? What is the value of `db.state` `db.user_access` `db.compatibility_level` and `db.containment` for those databases?

Comment: db.state is `normal` for the visible databases and `normal, autoclose` for the invisible ones. This also seems to be the issue... I removed `autoclose` and now all is visible.

Answer (score 0):

The db.state was `autoclose` for the invisible databases. Removing the `autoclose` feature from the database options resolved the issue.

Comment: Interesting. Kind of documented *"If a database is not ONLINE, or AUTO_CLOSE is set to ON and the database is closed, the values of some columns may be NULL"* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 Effectively, the database is closed even though `state` is `0`